Apache Nifi (ExecuteStreamCommand): Executable command python3 ended in an error:
I am trying to run the following script in the executestreamcommand processor, which will read the data from listfile and fetchfile processor. Then I am trying to merge the content of Excel files in parquet format in the following script but giving the python3 ended in an error
import os
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import sys
import io


def merge_and_split_parquet(data, output_dir, max_size=1 * 1024**3):
    """
    Merges and splits data into Parquet files based on size.

    Args:
        data (pd.DataFrame): Data to process.
        output_dir (str): Directory to save Parquet files.
        max_size (int): Maximum size in bytes for each Parquet file.
    """
    merged_data = pd.DataFrame()
    parquet_index = 1

    # Process the data row by row
    for _, row in data.iterrows():
        merged_data = pd.concat([merged_data, pd.DataFrame([row])])

        # Check the size of the DataFrame
        table = pa.Table.from_pandas(merged_data)
        buffer = pa.BufferOutputStream()
        pq.write_table(table, buffer)
        if buffer.size() >= max_size:
            # Write to a new Parquet file
            output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f"merged_{parquet_index}.parquet")
            pq.write_table(table, output_file)
            print(f"Generated {output_file}")
            merged_data = pd.DataFrame()  # Reset the DataFrame
            parquet_index += 1

    # Write any remaining data
    if not merged_data.empty:
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f"merged_{parquet_index}.parquet")
        pq.write_table(pa.Table.from_pandas(merged_data), output_file)
        print(f"Generated {output_file}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Ensure proper arguments are passed
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: python script.py <output_dir>")
        sys.exit(1)

    output_dir = sys.argv[1]

    # Ensure the output directory exists
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Read data from STDIN
    try:
        input_stream = sys.stdin.read()
        excel_data = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(input_stream.encode()))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading input data: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

    # Process and write Parquet files
    merge_and_split_parquet(excel_data, output_dir)

When i run the processor, it is giving the following error :
2024-11-25 07:46:07,540 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.p.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand ExecuteStreamCommand[id=4e7bd5aa-0193-1000-6154-675d13b6c0e5] Transferring StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=c534f453-59d0-4958-819e-01295652d375,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1732502757533-52, container=default, section=52], offset=1680, length=112],offset=0,name=3GNANKANA.xlsx,size=112] to nonzero status. Executable command python3 ended in an error: 

Below is my my workflow

My executestreamcommand configuration is as follows:

How can I resolve this?

i bet your script is throwing an error. check different properties and content of the "nonzero status" flow files.

is there anyway to see these error logs of my script in nifi? how can i debug?

check content and properties of nonzero

Thank You, i was getting this error Error reading input data: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udc8d' in position 22: surrogates not allowed  due to which i was not able to execute python. Now i am not able to receive any data in the executestreamcommand processor. Any guess why?

d83d looks like a surrogate prefix for utf-16 character

I have resolved the utf-8 related issues, but the executestreamcommand now getting no data in and out, and i am not getting any error but data is not processing not going in.

i'm not a python guru, but sys.stdin.read() reads inputstream as a string, then you are converting string to bytes, then you reading excel from bytes... you need to read excel from input stream directly.

I usually follow this - make Python script work in Standalone IDE once it is running successfully, then use it in NiFi.
